# How to set grid height row in extjs

Tags: extjs3

In my code I'm using four grids, I've set the row height in css like this:
`.x-grid3-row td {line-height: 50px;}`
and it sets the rows of all my grids.
So I need to set the height row of one of those grids.

Answer (score 2):

Based on id or cls class you can specify the CSS for eaxch component individually. For example,if you have grid with id `sample` then code will be:

```
.sample .x-grid3-row td {line-height: 50px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but another option is to use getRowClass on your viewConfig:

```
viewConfig: {
    getRowClass: function (record, rowIndex, rp, store) {
        rp.tstyle += 'height: 50px;';
    }
}
```

Comment: rowParams DEPRECATED. For row body use the getAdditionalData method of the rowbody feature. The getRowClass tstyle property is no longer supported. ExtJs 4.1.1.