# How to set height to single one Ext grid's row?

Tags: javascript, extjs

There is grid in ExtJs app.
In one row i want to show some text something about 300 symbols. So i need a set heigth to this row.
I found some [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743714/how-to-set-grid-height-row-in-extjs) using ViewConfig:

```
viewConfig: {
    getRowClass: function (record, rowIndex, rp, store) {
        rp.tstyle += 'height: 50px;';
    }
}
```

but how i understand its set height to all rows.  But how to do same only for one row?
Another question, its can be mad, but its possible to put memo into grid cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask on the proper values (usually id) or rowIndex and only sets for it:

```
viewConfig: {
    getRowClass: function (record, rowIndex, rp, store) {
        if(record.id == 439){ //id is some field from the store model
             rp.tstyle += 'height: 50px;';
        }

        //or
        if(rowIndex == 1){
             rp.tstyle += 'height: 50px;';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The getRowClass tstyle property is no longer supported for ExtJS 4.1.1.